# Can I programmatically remove funcionality from a shared library that is not used by a specified executable?

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-library

I have a library taking up a lot of disk space. Only one program I use links to that library.
I am pretty sure that the program uses only a tiny fraction of the functionality provided by that library.

Can I somehow programmatically remove functionality from the library that is not needed for running that program, so it will take up less disk space?
(Without having to recompile the library if possible)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible. Recompiling the program and linking the library statically is probably the only option. But you need to weigh the time it takes to do that against the cost of disk storage. What does a gigabyte cost nowadays? Less than the cup of coffee you'd be consuming while compiling the stuff.